# Record all EIP values during execution of a program?

Tags: windbg, ollydbg

Is there a way, by which I could be able to record all EIP values of a program during its execution?. Could I use Ollydbg's plugins or something else?

Comment: It will help if you can elaborate a little more on what you are trying to achieve. 
What do you intend to do with the EIP values ?

Comment: I have an app, which's crashed. I want to compare between normal execution and the crashed execution path, so that, I could figure out what cause the app crash.

Answer (score 1):

`ollydbg logs all eips` that were executed by using `Run Trace Feature` .

```
ollydbg 1.10 debug trace into ctrl+f11 and then view run trace 
ollydbg 2.01 trace trace into ctrl+f11 and then view run trace
```

windbg also has a lot of tracing variants like `step in / step over  till address / until return until branch until next call` etc etc   `ta / pa  tr pr th ph tct pct tc pc` etc etc pick your choice

also you can step till a specied address with simple trace t command as shown below

```
0:000> .printf "executable entry point is %x as denoted by symbol %y\n" , $exentry , @eip
executable entry point is 1012475 as denoted by symbol calc!WinMainCRTStartup (01012475)
0:000> p calc!WinMain 
01012477 68e0150001      push    offset calc!`string'+0x4 (010015e0)
0101247c e847030000      call    calc!_SEH_prolog (010127c8)
01012481 33db            xor     ebx,ebx
01012483 53              push    ebx
01012484 8b3d20100001    mov     edi,dword ptr [calc!_imp__GetModuleHandleA (01001020)]
0101248a ffd7            call    edi
0101248c 6681384d5a      cmp     word ptr [eax],5A4Dh
01012491 751f            jne     calc!WinMainCRTStartup+0x3d (010124b2)
```